# Function to Button in Python using PyQt4

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4, rdkit

I am trying to create a button in a window that will ultimately run a function that I have written from code.  My GUI code so far is as follows:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class PAINSFILTER(QtGui.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
    # Layout Init.
    self.setGeometry (650, 300, 600, 600)
    self.setWindowTitle('Data Viewer')
    self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('pill.png'))

    extractAction = QtGui.QAction("Quit", self)
    extractAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
    extractAction.setStatusTip('Leave App')
    extractAction.triggered.connect(self.close_application)

    self.statusBar()
    mainMenu = self.menuBar()
    fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu("&File")
    fileMenu.addAction(extractAction)

    self.uploadButton = QtGui.QPushButton('UPLOAD SDF', self)
    self.runfilterButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Run Filter', self)

    self.uploadButton.move (200, 50)
    self.runfilterButton.move (400,50)
    hBoxLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

    hBoxLayout.addWidget(self.uploadButton)
    hBoxLayout.addWidget(self.runfilterButton)
    self.setLayout(hBoxLayout)
    # Signal Init.
    self.connect(self.uploadButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.open)

def open (self):
    filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', '.')
    print 'Path file:', filename

def close_application(self):
    print ("Out")
    sys.exit()






def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = PAINSFILTER()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

    run()
```

The function I am trying to run through the button is a simple nested loop that will take the file I uploaded through the "upload sdf" button and run it through that function.  How do I link that function to a button using PyQt.  Here is the function for reference:

```
suppl = Chem.SDMolSupplier('data.sdf') #this .sdf file is the one uploaded through the upload sdf button
for m in suppl:
for x in range(len(pains_smarts)):
    if m.HasSubstructMatch(Chem.MolFromSmarts(pains_smarts[x])):
        match+=1
        has_pains.append(m)
        ss.append(c)
    else:
        no_match+=1
c+=1

for m in suppl:
for x in range(len(pains_smarts)):
    if m.HasSubstructMatch(Chem.MolFromSmarts(pains_smarts[x])):
        pname.append(pains_name[x])

for m in suppl:
for x in range(len(pains_smarts)):
    if m.HasSubstructMatch(Chem.MolFromSmarts(pains_smarts[x])):
        psmarts.append(pains_smarts[x])

uniquess = set(ss)


w = Chem.SDWriter('pains_structures.sdf')
notpains = Chem.SDWriter('no_pains_structures.sdf')
temp = 0

for m in suppl:
if temp in uniquess:
    w.write(m)
else:
    notpains.write(m)
temp += 1

w.flush()
notpains.flush()


import csv
csv_out = open("pains_compounds.csv", "w")
mywriter = csv.writer(csv_out)

for row in zip(ss, psmarts, pname):
mywriter.writerow(row)

csv_out.close()

new_suppl = Chem.SDMolSupplier("pains_structures.sdf")
ms = [x for x in new_suppl if x is not None]
for m in ms: tmp = AllChem.Compute2DCoords(m)
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
img = Draw.MolsToGridImage(ms, molsPerRow = 6, subImgSize = (200, 200),         legends = [x.GetProp("ID") for x in ms])
img.save("pains_img.png")
```

Comment: Could you explain what you have tried and why it hasn't worked? Have you tried sticking the second lot of code in the `open` method after getting the filename and using `suppl = Chem.SDMolSupplier(filename)`?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [PyQt signaling functionality](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html). For a QPushButton in particular it becomes:

```
 buttonName.clicked.connect(functionName)
```

Whenever a button is clicked, it will emit the signal `clicked` which now has `functionName` registered to execute. n.b. you do not put parentheses after the `functionName` as you do not want the function to execute, but rather pass the function itself. Additionally the function needs to satisfy the output of the [clicked signal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked), which emits a boolean (so functionName needs to take in that argument). In your case, since you want to pass another object, you can make a method:

```
def clickHandler(self,checked):
    #call function with object to pass as argument here
```

which calls your method and takes in the object you want to pass

Comment: FYI, PyQt does some magic and your function is allowed to have less arguments than the signal (so `clickHandler(self)` works too). I can't seem to find the documentation which details this though, but you can try it and see that it is true!

Comment: Also, It looks like this might not answer the question. On a second reading (I made the same original interpretation you did) they have already connected the button to a slot which opens a file selection dialog. They seems to want to know how to use the filename returned from that in their other code...

Comment: Right, now to use the filename returned from that in the other code is the main problem.